# Socket.io not able to recieve events

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket.io and I am emmiting in rooms but if a single tab of client side is opened then it is not receiving the event but multiple tabs are opened then except last tab are receivening the events

I have tried emmiting to and in methods to emmit in single and multiple rooms.